# Ambiguous implicit user defined conversions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

I recently wrote a couple of structs in .NET, to which I then added implicit conversion operators

**Example:**

```
public struct Alpha
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Alpha(Beta b)
    {
        return new Alpha() { value = b.value };
    }

    public static implicit operator Beta(Alpha a)
    {
        return new Beta() { value = a.value };
    }
}

public struct Beta
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Alpha(Beta b)
    {
        return new Alpha() { value = b.value };
    }

    public static implicit operator Beta(Alpha a)
    {
        return new Beta() { value = a.value };
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
Alpha a = default(Alpha);
Beta b = a;
// Ambiguous user defined conversions 'Alpha.implicit operator Beta(Alpha)' and 'Beta.implicit operator Beta(Alpha)' when converting from 'Alpha' to 'Beta'
```

I would like to know what the rules / best practices are surrounding implicit conversion in C#?

**Note to self:** My gut feeling is that types should not return objects of another type through implicit conversion? i.e. `Beta` should not return `Alpha` via implicit conversion, and vice-versa, however, `Beta` should return `Beta`, and `Alpha` should return `Alpha`

**Example (fixed):**

```
public struct Alpha
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Alpha(Beta b)
    {
        return new Alpha() { value = b.value };
    }
}

public struct Beta
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Beta(Alpha a)
    {
        return new Beta() { value = a.value };
    }
}
```

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `Alpha(Beta x)` defined in both classes, thus it is ambiguous which one should be used.  **Allow each class to handle only the conversion to itself.**  In other words, `struct Alpha` implements `Alpha(Beta b)` because it best knows how to create an instance of itself.  Also, I would consider implementing explicit conversions instead of implicit.  It can sometimes cause bugs or unexpected conversions accidentally, and when dealing with complex classes are often "lossy" conversions.

```
public struct Alpha
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Alpha(Beta b)
    {
        return new Alpha() { value = b.value };
    }
}

public struct Beta
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Beta(Alpha a)
    {
        return new Beta() { value = a.value };
    }
}
```

**The only time you'd likely implement "both ways" in a single class, is if the other class has no knowledge of your new class.**  This is the more common scenario when you want to support conversion to-from a pre-existing class/struct such as supporting conversion to-from a framework type:

```
public struct Alpha
{
    internal string value;

    public static implicit operator Alpha(string b)
    {
        return new Alpha() { value = b };
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Alpha a)
    {
        return  a.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, your assumpion is not correct (even though you wrote working code thanks to it). The problem in your  code is that you have defined the *same* conversion operators in both classes, this is why they are ambiguous; the compiler cannot decide which one to use.

You can read more in [section 6.4.3 (Evaluation of user-defined conversions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691302(v=vs.71).aspx) of the C# 4.0 Language Specification.