# What is the C# syntax to choose which ambiguous user-defined conversion operator to use?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, operator-overloading

In C#, if there are ambiguous user-defined conversion operators, can one of them be selected from the call site?

Consider this example (similar to the examples in [Ambiguous implicit user defined conversions in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775645/ambiguous-implicit-user-defined-conversions-in-net) and [Ambiguous user defined conversions, when converting from X to Y. C# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374053/ambiguous-user-defined-conversions-when-converting-from-x-to-y-c-sharp-net))

```cs
using System;

static class Program {
    class A {
        static public explicit operator A(B value) {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
            return new A();
        }
    }
    class B {
        static public explicit operator A(B value) {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
            return new A();
        }
    }
    public static void Main() {
        A a = (A)new B();
    }
}
```

[If one of the operators is commented out, the code will compile](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUH1TANgAIMzMB2EgbzwEhyBBWhx4sgZhIFMAPAA4AbAJYBjEcBIB7ATzABDYNLAkmACgBCJAG4KhEHgEpWueucIBOdQCImNowG42jalB4B3NeqdsAvgwBZuTadGb0APQAVHgkcfFxhKSo3PzC4pIycorKqhraegbGpubs1jaaDs7hriTuXhq+4UEJCVERgQwY6CX0LAokALwk6kxG9SSaPtX0QX5AA==). This is a theoretical question (the practical solution is not to have ambiguous conversion operators), but is there some special syntax at the call site to call one of them specifically (by editing `(A)new B()`)?  Or is it impossible and forces the classes to be rewritten?

Comment: If it is possible i am not aware on how this could be done. But my opinion on these have always been that the compiler should just throw a warning for a double (or triple who knows) X to Y operator.

Answer (score 1):

The [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#processing-of-user-defined-explicit-conversions) says this:

- If U contains exactly one user-defined conversion operator that converts from SX to TX, then this is the most specific conversion operator.
- Otherwise, if U contains exactly one lifted conversion operator that converts from SX to TX, then this is the most specific conversion operator.
- **Otherwise, the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.**

So, basically this is invalid code and the compiler will refuse to accept it.